# Angular Material SnackBar `onAction()` method doesn't trigger

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a problem with Angular Material SnackBar `onAction()` method, it doesn't trigger after the button is clicked.
I've opened SnackBar and subscribed to `onAction`, `afterDismissed` and `afterOpened` methods. Other methods are triggered, but not `onAction`. Does anyone know what should I do? I have this problem since last Angular update from 9 to 11.

```
constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

private openSnackBar() {
  let mySnackBar: MatSnackBarRef<TextOnlySnackBar> = this.snackBar.open('Message', 'Close');
    mySnackBar.afterDismissed().subscribe((matSnackBarDismiss: MatSnackBarDismiss) => {
      console.log('afterDismissed');
    });
    mySnackBar.onAction().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('onAction');
      mySnackBar.dismiss();
    });
    mySnackBar.afterOpened().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('afterOpened');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: openSnackBar is marked private, did you try making it public?

Comment: @BrendanB `openSnackBar` is used only inside this class. SnacBar is opened, and it closes after 10s (when I add duration).

Comment: I see, 
I also see dismiss() being called within onAction, unsure if this is causing some issue.
May want to try without the dismiss

Comment: @BrendanB I don't think it is a problem with the code inside the subscription. I tried without calling `dismiss` and it is the same.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's definitely not just you. I'll post here if I find something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with internal CSS. Probably somebody removed some CSS property (I think it was `pointer-events`), and it was included in the Angular update. I fixed a local CSS and it works now.